# Laravel "Class MyClass not found"

Tags: php, laravel

### My problem:

I have a controller that calls a method from another controller for some information. However, Laravel isn't able to locate the class in that controller.

> FatalErrorException in TradesController.php line 35: Class 'Profile'
>   not found

## What I have tried:

I am using Laravel 5.2 and have created the controller with `php artisan make:controller Profile` to ensure that any possible internal pointers (in lack of better vocabulary) are created - even though my understanding is that Laravel 5.2 does this automatically as long as controllers are in the \app directory.

They both reside within \app\Http\Controllers

## My code

## TradesController calls class Profile

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Profile;
use Session;
use Auth;

class TradesController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function showInventory (Request $request){

         .....

         // Following three calls all fail

                $profile = new Profile;
                $profile = Profile()->linkToProfile();
                $profile = Profile::linkToProfile();

         .....


        return($output);
    }
}
```

## MY class Profile-controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use Auth;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(Request $request){

        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function linkToProfile (Request $request) {
        return("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php artisan make:controller xxx` creates a class `xxxController` therefore your class is `ProfileController` not `Profile`.

Comment: I cannot believe how simple my mistakes are with Laravel sometimes. Thank you :)

Comment: Also do not forget to composer dump autoload